# Dropdown toggle stops working after adding modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap dropdown which worked fine till now.Now i have added two bootstrap modals to my code.My dropdown doesn't work after i add modals to my code.If i remove modals it just works fine.I cant figure out why.
Does this has something to do with data-toggle as i can see its the only common thing between both of them
This is my code.

```
<div class="my-container" ng-controller="compCategoryCtrl">
<div class="compare-table">
    <div class="head-info">
        <h3>Select colleges to compare</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="find-colleges">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle find" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-model="selected_value1">{{selected_value1}}
                    <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu find-menu">
                            <li ng-repeat=" clg in college_list" ng-click="set_clg1(clg)">{{clg.college}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle find" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-model="selected_value2">{{selected_value2}}
                     <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu find-menu">
                            <li ng-repeat=" clg in college_list" ng-click="set_clg2(clg)">{{clg.college}}</li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-4 go">
                    <button class="btn compare_buton trigger open" ng-click="fetch()">Go</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="nav-for-table slider close">
        <div id="home">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">

                <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data1[0]">

                    <td class="col-md-6 head-field active">{{key}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="x in data1">
                        {{x[key]}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="x in data1">
                        {{data2[$index][key]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-6 head-field active">Departments</td>
                    <td class="col-md-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#show1">
                        Click here to view Departments
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#show2">
                        Click here to view Departments
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="show1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;z-index: 9999;margin-top: 100px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Department Information</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <table class="table table-striped" id="tblGrid">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Branch</th>
                        <th>Seats</th>
                        <th>Rating</th>
                        <th>Placements</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in dept1">
                        <td>{{x.branch}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.seats}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.rating}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.placement}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->

</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="show2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;z-index: 9999;margin-top: 100px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Department Information</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <table class="table table-striped" id="tblGrid">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Branch</th>
                        <th>Seats</th>
                        <th>Rating</th>
                        <th>Placements</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in dept2">
                        <td>{{x.branch}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.seats}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.rating}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.placement}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->

</div>
```

```
<script>
$('.trigger.open').on('click', function () {
    $('.slider').removeClass('close');
});
$('.trigger.close').on('click', function () {
    $('.slider').addClass('close');
});
</script>
```

Can somebody please help.

Comment: can you use your console to see errors ?

Comment: Its not showing any errors.Nothing happens when i click on dropdown

Comment: I can only see that you have duplicated IDs for the tables in modals "tblGrid" but I don't think this is a problem. Just try to change them first and see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the inline styles you have on each Modal:

`style="display: block;z-index: 9999;margin-top: 100px;"`

Once those are removed the modals fire as expected.  I might also recommend removing the `.close` class from `<div class="nav-for-table slider">` as that class is used by Bootstrap and might cause various display conflicts.

See this Bootply for a functional example:

https://www.bootply.com/dFixsdYLpG

Comment: Thanks a lot. I created a separate class and wrote that style there and it works perfectly now.Saved my day :-)